# Can you use MemoryCache.Default as a singleton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, memorycache

I've got an ASP.NET API web site.  We are caching certain data inside `MemoryCache.Default`.

This has been working fairly well till now, but some new code has been written, and suddenly now the `MemoryCache` is getting cleared.  I verified by checking the hash code of `MemoryCache.Default`, and at some point in code execution, the hash code is changing, i.e. it's a brand new cache we're suddenly working with.

I was under the impression that `MemoryCache.Default` was basically a singleton, and anything I cache in there is going to remain there for the lifespan of my web site.  Either that assumption is wrong, or else there's some new code somewhere out there that is explicitly blowing away the cache.  I looked for all references to `MemoryCache` in code, and found nothing suspicious.  Are there any other seemingly unrelated method calls that might trigger the destruction of the default memory cache?  Or have I misunderstood how `MemoryCache` works?

Comment: Is the app pool restarting (perhaps after the idle timeout)? That would do it.

Comment: As @Gabirel Luci suggests I'd also look at your app pool recycle settings - IIS will forcibly recycle app pools in many circumstances, and even "just in case" so in-memory caches are very fragile things.

Comment: No, it's not recycling.  The bug is showing up in a single unit of work in my debug environment.  One minute the cache is fine, hit F5 to the next breakpoint, and suddenly the cache is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.  There was a 3rd party tool introduced into the web API.  Something it's doing is triggering a shutdown of the web site (proved by catching breakpoint in `Application_End`).  Not throwing an exception, but nonetheless after calling the tool, the web site gets shut down, which it doesn't if we comment out that line.

Still working on a solution, but at least now we know the cause...